# How to find out not null values in oracle (25 Columns)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL.  I have 2 scenarios:

1)  To find out if at least one of the 25 columns is not null (Could be more than 1)

2)  or if all 25 columns are not null

Do i need to write not Null condition for  all 25 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce should help, something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(field1, field2, field3...) is NULL THEN 'AllNULL'
ELSE 'OneOrMoreNotNULL' END as 'NULLcontent' FROM tbl
```

Comment: I need to find out if data has one  column  null or all column nulls

Comment: @Aditya kommu This meets your spec as stated in requirement #1 of "at least one of the 25 columns is not null".  If this has changed, edit your original post via the edit link.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE LENGTH( SUBSTR(COL_1, 1, 1) ||
                    SUBSTR(COL_2, 1, 1) ||  
                    ...                 ||
                    SUBSTR(COL_25, 1, 1)                     
                   )
         WHEN 25 THEN 'ALL NOT NULL'
         WHEN 24 THEN '1 COLUMN NULL'
         ...
     END CASE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

If you have columns different from `varchar`, you'll need to cast them to `varchar` to use this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use GREATEST (or LEAST) to test if any items in a list are null (for expressions of a consistent datatype).

```
select greatest(owner, object_name, to_char(object_id), to_char(data_object_id)) x, 
       owner, object_name, object_id, data_object_id 
from all_objects where object_name in ('DUAL');
```

If any of the values in the list of expressions supplied to GREATEST is null, the return value will be null. It will only return a non-null value if all the expressions are not null.